# How can I edit .css files rightly in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I can not edit .css files correctly and comfortably without right editor. My .css files are like this.
￼[image]

I tried to find .css plugin but failed with this.
[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Buy a license for the commercial version.

Comment: Um,that seems too much heavy for me. Is that the only way to fix this?